# iPad scrollbar with css(-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) missing when onorientationchange

Tags: css, ipad

I want to show some 'ul' result in a small div with scrollbars instead of that the user need to scroll the full page, now i have made it work by css:**-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;**,Usually it work but when i change the view of ipad it broke down.

eg:

```
<div id="leftpanel">ul ul ul ul</div>
#leftPanel{
       overflow-y: scroll;
       overflow-x: visible;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
       height：100%；
}
```

In Landscape view the height of div is not enough to show all 'ui' then scroll bar is work,at this time,change the view to Portrait view,the height of div is enough to show all 'ul' so that the scroll bar is disable automatic,finally changed the view back to Landscape the **scroll bar is missing,is not scrollable**
 Is there a solution to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this helps :)**

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    if($('#thumbwrapper').is(":visible")==true)
    {
       //thumbholder is inner div and thumbwrapper outer 
        $('#thumbholder').height(900); 
        window.setTimeout(delayFix, 10);
    }

});

function delayFix()
{
    if($('#thumbwrapper').is(":visible")==true)
    {
        $('#thumbholder').height($("#thumbwrapper").height() + 20);
    }
}
```